# What's the difference between "Pixel rate bound: 0" and "Pixel rate bound: 1"?

Tags: xcode, metal

When running a macOS Metal app under the Xcode GPU Debugger and examining the Counters, under the "Potential Hotspots/Bottlenecks" section, the following warning appears for some render command encoders: 

[image]

But some other encoders display the warning: 
[image]

Many encoders don't display either warning, so this doesn't appear to be a boolean value.

So what *does* this mean?